# Open an URL with Javascript from a web app

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

I have this code in my html javascript: `window.location.assign('https://script.google.com/a/macros/smapostols.org/s/AKfycbz2BP0c6D7fdDDJUlRHcsCvNKoMuHW1_tN_wVy5iFs/dev?p=ok');`

and it doesn't work, error: `The page script.google.com refused connection`.

This works fine with another URL (i.e. `http://www.google.com`) and also works fine with: `window.open('https://script.google.com/a/macros/smapostols.org/s/AKfycbz2BP0c6D7fdDDJUlRHcsCvNKoMuHW1_tN_wVy5iFs/dev?p=ok');`

Does anybody know the problem?

Comment: Can you show your `doGet()`?

Comment: function doGet(e) {
  
  if(e.parameters.p == "ok"){
    return carregaPDJ(e.parameters.u);
  }
  else {
    return carregaLOG();
  }

}

function carregaLOG(){

   var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("log");
   return tmp.evaluate();

}


function carregaPDJ(usuari){

   var tmp = HtmlService.createTemplateFromFile("pdj");
   
   tmp.usuari = usuari;
   return tmp.evaluate()
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);

}

Answer (score 1):

#### Possible Answer:

*Try setting the `XFrameOptionsMode` to `ALLOWALL` when serving your HTML.*

#### More Information:

As per the developer documentation on [`XFrameOptionsMode`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/x-frame-options-mode):

> An enum representing the `X-Frame-Options` modes that can be used for client-side [`HtmlService`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/html-service) scripts.
> ...
> Setting `XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL will let any site iframe the page, so the developer should implement their own protection against clickjacking.
>
> #### Properties
>
> | Property | Type | Description |
> | --- | --- | --- |
> | `ALLOWALL` | `Enum` | No `X-Frame-Options` header will be set. This will let any site iframe the page, so the developer should implement their own protection against clickjacking. |
> | `DEFAULT` | `Enum` | Sets the default value for the `X-Frame-Options` header, which preserves normal security assumptions. If a script does not set an `X-Frame-Options` mode, Apps Script uses this mode as the default. |

#### Example:

```js
function doGet() {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('filename')
    .setSandboxMode(HtmlService.SandboxMode.IFRAME)
    .setXFrameOptionsMode(HtmlService.XFrameOptionsMode.ALLOWALL);
}
```

#### References:

- [Enum XFrameOptionsMode | Apps Script | Google Developers](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/html/x-frame-options-mode)

Comment: As an additional information, in the case that Web Apps is used, as an important point, when the Google Apps Script of Web Apps is modified, when you add an explanation that it modifies the current deployment version as new version without changing the URL of Web Apps, I thought that it might be useful for OP and other users. Because I sometimes forget this.